# how to add the hash key to firebase OTP sms body section

Tags: hash, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

we have checked the autofill functionality for android. so we needed the 11 char hash key to be added into the OTP SMS body.   how to add that into firebase phone auth OTP message.

we referred to this documentation:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview

Comment: @Steve Vinoski Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: yes, we have to enable related auto verification API on GCP. then this is solved. after that we can receive the hash key from firebase auth sms

Comment: could you please let me know the verification API name. I just searched the GCP but didn't find any. Thanks

Comment: @Arjun you got his working ?

Comment: @Francis_M the gcp api name ?

Comment: search Android Device Verification on the GCP console.

Comment: @epynic I did not find it then so kept that on hold. Did you find the solution?

Comment: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/playintegrity.googleapis.com. The Play Integrity API has replaced SafetyNet Attestation and Android Device Verification.

Answer (score 3):

**As of 2nd July 2021:**

This is expected behavior - your application's name is long enough that it crowds out the application hash from the SMS.

Shortening the name of the app is the only fix for now

Read More
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2688#issuecomment-860940110

Answer (score 0):

We have to enable related auto verification API on the Google Cloud Platform (GCP). then this is solved. after that we can receive the hash key from the Firebase auth sms.

Goto GCP clicks on console search Android Device Verification.

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/playintegrity.googleapis.com
The Play Integrity API has replaced SafetyNet Attestation and Android Device Verification.